# How to change the default saved user and password for sites in browser?

Tags: browser, accounts

A friend borrowed my phone and logged in to a website with it (and logged out). However, after that, his account became my browser's default account for that site. Every time I try to log in to the website, the user and password fields become automatically filled with his user and password. This is very annoying because I have to delete these and type my user id and password repeatedly. Is there any way to change/clear the default id and password?

The browser is Galaxy S stock browser, and the OS version is 2.2.

**[edit]** Another question: Why did his account become the default? I mean, I logged in repeatedly before and after his logging in, but his one-time login gets picked as the default,

Comment: Could it be a ‘Remember me’ feature of the web site that is causing the username to be remembered, rather than the remember credentials feature of the stock browser? Which web site is it that causes the issue and does it have a ‘Remember me’ feature? If so then the solution is to use it to remember ‘you’ instead of remember ‘him’.

Comment: No, there is no remember me feature in the website. And it's not that the website remembers him. Usually it remembers me and I am logged in, but when I have to fill the user and password fields, the browser fills it with his user/password instead of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lie Ryan’s answer is probably the ultimate solution but it might be worth trying the less severe clear options first. That is, try the browser clear options in the following order: history, cache, all cookie data, form data and finally passwords. One of those lesser options might just resolve the issue, without having to lose all of your saved passwords.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to clear only a single saved password in the stock Browser, but you can do `Menu > More > Settings > Clear passwords` to clear all saved password.